# Prolog lists (using stemming function)

Tags: list, prolog

I know this is a very simple question but I seem to be having some problems.

I am trying to stem a list of words using porter_stem but I am getting an error:

> Out of local stack

This is my code:

```
stemming([],[]).
stemming([H|T], A) :-
    stemming(T,Answer),
    porter_stem(H,S),
    append(Answer,S,A).
```

Basically the pseudocode for this is as follows:

```
for all items in list
    stem item
    add item to list2
    return list2
```

Can anyone please point me in the right direction please?

Comment: well, the first thing your stemming predicate does is to call stemming, it should be the last thing it does.

Comment: Thanks, fixed. Still gets the same error though :/

Comment: I can detail a normal recursion to you if you want, but did you try to use `maplist/3` or equivalent depending on your prolog implementation ? something like `maplist(porter_stem, List, Result).` would suffice.

Comment: wow thanks. i didnt know maplist existed :O

Comment: @Mog: post that as an answer!

Comment: you are appending each new element at the end of the accumulating list: `append(Answer,S,A)`. This is quadratic - it has to go over and over from the start of the list, building new copy and discarding old, only to add *one* element each time. You could try `stemming([H|T],[S|R]):- porter_stem(H,S),stemming(T,R)`. That's kind of re-implementing `maplist/2`. Also, see if [this approach](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8869485/lazy-lists-in-prolog) help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using `maplist/3` or equivalent depending on your prolog implementation: something like `maplist(porter_stem, List, Result).` would suffice.

If you're interested in learning how to build a proper recursion, post a comment and I'll try to expand my answer :)

Comment: Thank you so much! If I could understand what was wrong with the code I pasted, I would be everso grateful.