# Lazy lists in Prolog?

Tags: list, stream, prolog, lazy-evaluation, lazy-sequences

Is it possible to have lazy lists in Prolog? Something like the following:

```
ones([1 | Y]) :- ones(Y).
```

Although this obviously doesn't work as it's written.

Comment: a tweak for what you wrote does the job: `ones([1|Y]):- freeze(Y, ones(Y)).`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Markus Triska [placed here](https://www.metalevel.at/) in public domain [some code](https://www.metalevel.at/various/prost.pl) worth to study:

```
/* - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
   Prolog stream/lazy list demonstration

   Written 2005 by Markus Triska (triska@gmx.at)
   Public domain code.
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - */
```

The title of the document ([prost](https://www.metalevel.at/various/prost), for Prolog streams) maybe make the document a bit difficult to find, but make sense.
Quoting from the above:

> Here, "stream" is used in the sense of "sequence", "delayed list",
>   "lazy list" etc. as in Structure and Interpretation of Computer
>   Programs, not in the sense of a Prolog input/output stream.

Answer (score 13):

Here's a lazy-list Hamming numbers in Prolog using a "generator idiom".

The more I think about it the more it seems to me the lazy lists of Haskell are just open-ended (a.k.a. ["difference"](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/difference-lists/info)) lists of Prolog, and [*corecursion*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corecursion) just a fancy name for the top-down list building of [tail recursion modulo cons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call#Tail_recursion_modulo_cons). Also, Haskell is implicitly *set once* language, while (non-backtracking subset of) Prolog is *explicitly* set once.

The mind-mangling "tying-the-knot" technique is actually nothing more than awkwardly implemented late variable instantiation. And, *everything is a generator* in Haskell, with memoizing storage a universal access mediator. But anyway,

The following implements the *head-forced* streams (of [SICP](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sicp/info) variety), where if an element is forced, all the elements preceding it in the list are already forced as well.

```ml
:- dynamic( next/3 ).

% (* collect N elements produced by a generator in a row: *)
take( 0, Next, Z-Z, Next) :- !.
take( N, Next, [A|B]-Z, NextZ) :- N > 0, !, next( Next, A, Next1),
  N1 is N-1,
  take( N1, Next1, B-Z, NextZ).

% (* a "generator" provides a specific `next/3` implementation *)
next( hamm( A2,B, C3,D, E5,F, [H|G]), H, hamm( X,U, Y,V, Z,W, G) ) :- 
  H is min(A2, min(C3, E5)),
  (   A2 =:= H ->  B = [N2|U], X is N2*2  ;  (X,U) = (A2,B) ),
  (   C3 =:= H ->  D = [N3|V], Y is N3*3  ;  (Y,V) = (C3,D) ),
  (   E5 =:= H ->  F = [N5|W], Z is N5*5  ;  (Z,W) = (E5,F) ).

% (* Hamming numbers generator init state: *)
mkHamm( hamm( 1,X, 1,X, 1,X, X) ).       

% (* A calling example: main( +Number) *)
main(N) :- 
    mkHamm(G),        take(20,G,A-[],_),  write(A), nl,  
    take(N-1,G,_,G2), take(2,G2,B-[],_),  write(B), nl.

% (* testing ... *)
2 ?- main(1000).
[1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9,10,12,15,16,18,20,24,25,27,30,32,36]
[51200000,51840000]
true.
```

Simple, eh? For `ones` we just define

```ml
next( ones, 1, ones).
```

as there is no (change in) state there, and then call it as e.g.

```ml
take( N, ones, A-[], _), writeln(A).
```

For Haskell-like integer enumerations we define

```ml
next( fromBy(F,B), F, fromBy(F2,B)) :- F2 is F+B.
```

and call `take(8, fromBy(3,2), A-[], _)` to get `A = [3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17].` Fibonacci sequence is simply

```ml
next( fib(A,B), A, fib(B,C)) :- C is A+B.
```

With `take(20, fib(0,1), FS-[], _)`, a 20-elements list `FS` of Fibonacci numbers is defined.

*Memoizing* Fibonacci sequence is

```ml
mkFibs( fibs([0|L], L) ) :- L = [1|_].
next( fibs([A|L], L), A, fibs(L, L2) ):- 
    L = [B|L2], L2 = [C|_], (var(C) -> C is A+B ; true).
```

Now restarting from a previously used generator won't recalculate the numbers but instead will re-fetch the previously calculated members of the sequence, where available. This internal shared open-ended storage is fragile to misuse i.e. wrongful instantiation (**edit:** *of its not-yet-set last tail pointer variable*). This is the reason for `take` building new storage for its answer, instead of exposing the internal one.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, it's possible to have lazy lists in Prolog.  Here's an infinite, lazy list of ones using `freeze/2`.

```
ones(L) :-
  freeze(L, (L=[1|T],ones(T)) ).
```

Using it at the top-level looks like this:

```
?- ones(Ones), [A,B,C|_] = Ones.
A = B = C = 1.
```

You might also enjoy the [list_util pack](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pack/list?p=list_util) (for SWI-Prolog) which contains several lazy list predicates.

Comment: how would the infinite Fibonacci sequence look like?

Comment: @WillNess I put together an infinite, lazy Fibonacci sequence for you https://gist.github.com/4644762  It's not as concise as Haskell, but still fun.

Comment: thank you very much for the example. ... I personally would prefer the name `delay` in place of `freeze`. The latter is so final, and implies - for me - the need to explicitly call `thaw` on a freezed var. While the former is more intuitive. I'm used to `delay` of Scheme, so it makes more sense to me. :)

Comment: @WillNess: What is `thaw`? Seems to be something opposed to `freeze`.

Comment: @false I was referring to my misreading of the name `freeze`, my first impression about it, having not read the manual. :)

Comment: @WillNess: I suspected somewhat that you were referring to `freeze(Term, Frozen)` and `melt(Frozed, Thawed)` which had very problematic semantic properties.

Comment: @false is this TAoP's `freeze` and `melt_new`? Are they at all related to the delaying `freeze` as used here? I didn't quite get where and for what are they needed, from the book. Is there any link to some discussion about them, and the associated problems? Google search didn't bring up much. ... I tried reading Boizumault once but the use of `freeze` there was confusing to me, having just read TAoP. Will appreciate any pointers. :)

Comment: @WillNess: TAoP's constructs permit to relate a variable to a corresponding atom (and vice versa). That in itself is semantically pretty problematic and has not been adapted by other systems. It was an attempt to make meta-programming cleaner. I'd say it failed. Boizumault's freeze/2 is the same as the one in SICStus, SWI, YAP, B and others.

Answer (score 4):

well, you could define an infinite list of ones (or anything else) as:

```
H = [1|H].
```

use:

```
4 ?- H=[1|H], [A1|T1] = H, [A2|T2] = T1, T1=T2.
H = [1|**],
A1 = 1,
T1 = [1|**],
A2 = 1,
T2 = [1|**].
```

Of course, this won't work if you want a list of primes/fibonacci/anything not so trivial.

You could write some predicates that would emulate the behavior of a lazy list but I do not think that there are any  libraries/standardized way to do it (at least in swi-prolog) (:( haskell's lazy list is such a nice feature).

Comment: +1. Incomplete data structures are the closest to lazy lists that Prolog has to offer.

Comment: Don't you think that when/2, freeze/2, dif/2 can be used to simulate laziness ?

Comment: @joel76 yup, I think that they are indeed useful building blocks to simulate laziness

Comment: @joel76: yes, see my answer, which uses suspensions (ECLiPSe's equivalent to SWI's when/2 and freeze/2)

Answer (score 3):

Here's a slightly different take on lazy lists, which uses suspensions. It's written in ECLiPSe, but you should be able to replicate it in other flavours of Prolog.

It uses an attributed variable to record the current length of the lazy list, and constructs new members of the list when the lower bound of the variable's domain is raised.

I assume that the predicate that is executed to construct list members has arity 3, and the three arguments are: in-state, out-state, and result. It's easy to adapt the example to general goals, though.

I also used a "store", which is a non-logical hash storage, in order to quickly retrieve the n-th element of the list by avoiding to iterate over the list. Using a store is not essential, but iterating over a long list again and again can be expensive.

Here's the predicate that makes the lazy list:

```
:- lib(ic). % load IC library (constraints over intervals)

% make new lazy list
% lazy_list(-,-,-,++,++)
lazy_list(List, Store, E, Pred, InitState) :-
    store_create(Store),
    E #>= 0,
    suspend(generate_nth_el(E, 0, List, Store, Pred, InitState), 3, E->ic:min).
```

`List` is the new list, `Store` is a handle of a store, `Pred` the functor of the predicate that generates the list members, `InitState` the initial state, and `E` the variable that is used to trigger the list creation.

New list members are created when the lower bound of `E` is raised. In that case, `generate_nth_el/6` is woken:

```
generate_nth_el(E, Last, List, Store, Pred, LastState) :-
    This is Last+1,
    List = [NextVal|Tail],
    Goal =.. [Pred, LastState, NextState, NextVal],
    call(Goal),  % create next element
    store_set(Store, This, NextVal), % add next element to store
    get_min(E, MinE),
    (
        This == MinE
    ->
        % when reached the lower bound, suspend again
        suspend(generate_nth_el(E, This, Tail, Store, Pred, NextState), 3, E->ic:min)
    ;
        % else continue with extending the list
        generate_nth_el(E, This, Tail, Store, Pred, NextState)
    ).
```

The predicate `generate_nth_el/6` is purely for internal use, and should not be called by the user.

Finally, here's a predicate to retrieve the n-th element:

```
% nth_el(++,+,++,-)
nth_el(N, E, Store, V) :-
    N > 0,
    E #>= N,                % force creation of new elements
    store_get(Store, N, V). % get nth element from store.
```

It adds a constraint that `E` must be at least as large as `N`. If this increases the lower bound, the list is extended. The n-th element is then retrieved from the store.

As an example, here's a version of the fibonacci number predicate with in- and out-states as used in the code above:

```
fib((0,0), (0,1), 0) :- !.
fib(StateIn, StateOut, B) :-
    StateIn  = (A, B),
    StateOut = (B, C),
    C is A+B.
```

And here's how it works:

```
?- lazy_list(List, Store, E, fib, (0,0)),
   nth_el(5, E, Store, F5),
   nth_el(3, E, Store, F3),
   nth_el(10, E, Store, F10).
List = [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34|_1179]
Store = 'STORE'(16'8ee279a0)
E = E{10 .. 1.0Inf}
F5 = 3
F3 = 1
F10 = 34
There is 1 delayed goal.
Yes (0.00s cpu)
```

Note, though, that lazy lists are often used in other languages to achieve behaviour that in Prolog can be implemented through simple backtracking.

Answer (score 2):

```prolog
% A simple generic solution using SWI-Prolog 

% Returns a prefix of a lazy sequence

prefix(Prefix,PrefixLength,LazySequenceName) :-
    apply(LazySequenceName,[LazySequence]),
    length(Prefix,PrefixLength),
    append(Prefix,_,LazySequence).

% Lazy sequence of natural numbers

nat(LazySequence) :- 
    nat(0,LazySequence).
nat(Item,LazySequence) :-
    freeze(LazySequence,
      (LazySequence=[Item|Rest], Next is Item+1, nat(Next,Rest)) ).

% Lazy sequence of Fibonacci numbers

fib(LazySequence) :- 
    fib(1,0,LazySequence).
fib(A,B,LazySequence) :-
    freeze(LazySequence,
       (LazySequence=[C|Rest], C is A+B, fib(B,C,Rest))).

% Examples

test :-
    prefix(N,10,nat), format('Ten first natural numbers: ~w~n',[N]),
    prefix(F,10,fib), format('Ten first Fibonacci numbers: ~w~n',[F]),
    fib(S), nth1(100,S,X), format('The hundredth Fibonacci number: ~w~n',[X]).
```