# Prolog - List of sequence from f0 to fN

Tags: prolog

The question require me to write a predicate `seqList(N, L)`, which is satisfied when L is the list `[f0, . . . , fN]`.

Where the `fN = fN-1 + fN-2 + fN-3`

My code is to compare the head of a list given, and will return true or false when compared.

```
seqList(_,[]).
seqList(N,[H|T]) :-
    N1 is N - 1,
    seq(N,H),
    seqList(N1,T).
```

However, it only valid when the value is reversed,
e.g. seqList(3,[1,1,0,0]) will return true, but the list should return me true for
seqList(3,[0,0,1,1]). Is there any way for me to reverse the list and verifies it correctly?

Comment: the definition of your predicate is unclear to me. Plus, you should add your seq predicate, here you don't have all the code.

Comment: are you banned to use [reverse](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=reverse/2)/2?

Comment: im sry for that unclear @Mog any way, im currently not in home, will upload all those details to you in no time. Well, i can use anything i can as long as i can did the job, anyway using the reverse will cause my list to keep flipping each time it recurse going down to the base case.@chac

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you want to generate `N` elements of a sequence `f` such that `f(N) = f(N-1) + f(N-2) + f(N-3)` where `f(X)` is the `X`-th element of the sequence list, `0`-based. The three starting elements must be pre-set as part of the specification as well. You seem to be starting with `[0,0,1, ...]`.

Using the approach from [Lazy lists in Prolog?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8882745/849891):

```
seqList(N,L):- N >= 3, !,
   L=[0,0,1|X], N3 is N-3, take(N3, seq(0,0,1), X-[], _).

next( seq(A,B,C), D, seq(B,C,D) ):- D is A+B+C.
```

Now all these functions can be fused and inlined, to arrive at one recursive definition.

---

But you can do it directly. You just need to write down the question, to get the solution back.

```
question(N,L):-
```

Since you start with 0,0,1, ... *write it down:*

```
    L = [0, 0, 1 | X],
```

since the three elements are given, we only need to find out `N-3` more. ***Write it down:***

```
    N3 is N-3,
```

you've now reduced the problem somewhat. You now need to find `N-3` elements and put them into the `X` list. Use a *worker* predicate for that. It also must know the three preceding  numbers at each step:

```
    worker( N3, 0, 0, 1, X).
```

So just **write down** what the *worker* must know:

```
worker(N, A, B, C, X):-
```

if `N` is 0, we must stop. `X` then is an empty list. ***Write it down.***

```
    N = 0, X = [] .
```

Add another clause, for when `N` is greater than 0.

```
worker(N, A, B, C, X):-
    N > 0,
```

We know that the next element is the sum of the three preceding numbers. ***Write that down***.

```
    D is A + B + C,
```

the next element in the list is the top element of our argument list (the last parameter). ***Write it down:***

```
    X = [D | X2 ],
```

now there are one less elements to add. ***Write it down:***

```
    N2 is N - 1,
```

To find the rest of the list, the three last numbers are `B, C,` and `D`. Then the rest is found by `worker` ***in exactly the same way:***

```
    worker( N2, B, C, D, X2).
```

That's it. The `question` predicate is your solution. Rename it to your liking.