# Prolog: Is f(X) = X unifiable or not?

Tags: prolog, unification

My understanding of unification is a little patchy. I understand basic unification, but I'm having issues getting my head round terms which are not unifiable.

I was watching a youtube tutorial on unification which stated if a variable is trying to be unified against a term which contains that variable, then it is not unifiable.

However when I type `?- f(X) = X` into prolog, it returns something along the lines of... `f(f(f(f(f(f(...)))))) ?`

I understand why this is... but I don't understand if this means it is unifiable or not, as I would have expected it just to return 'no' if it wasn't unifiable. Am I right in thinking that trying to unify f(X) = X fails the occurs check, thus making them not unifiable?

Comment: For something to be *unifiable* it must be so *with* something else. So when you as *Is `f(X) = X` unifiable?* do you really mean, *Is `f(X)` unifiable with `X`?* By the way, which Prolog implementation are you using? DIfferent Prologs respond differently to `f(X) = X`.

Comment: If you read, for example, [here](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=unify_with_occurs_check%2f2) and [here](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=flags#flag:occurs_check), you'll find that the answer is: *it depends*. It depends upon whether your Prolog does an occurs check, or supports it as an option. According to the SWI documentation, with a query such as `f(X) = X`, ***unification succeeds**, creating an infinite tree* if `occurs_check` is set to false. If `occurs_check` is set to true, then unification will fail.

Comment: @lurker I'm using Prolog specifically, but I'm talking more in general logic. I assumed Prolog would just be the same.

Comment: As I mentioned in my prior comment, `X` is unifiable with `f(X)` depending upon the system and its settings. Unless you're asking if it *should* be unifiable, ever, logically, which is a matter of opinion.

Comment: @lurker this should be an answer!

Comment: Search for prolog + coinduction. E.g. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26963657/is-an-infinite-list-of-ones-sane

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33753953/772868) plus references.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you are right: In logic, a variable *x* is of course *not* syntactically unifiable with the term *f(x)* on the grounds that the variable itself *occurs as a strict subterm* of *f(x)*.

For this reason, the so-called [**occurs check**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occurs_check) causes the unification to fail.

As is correctly noted in that article, Prolog implementations typically *omit* the occurs check for efficiency reasons, and that can lead to unsound inferences.

However, you can always perform unification *with* occurs check in Prolog by using the ISO predicate `unify_with_occurs_check/2`. Exactly as expected, the unification you are asking about *fails* in that case:

```
?- unify_with_occurs_check(X, f(X)).
false.
```

Note that in some Prolog systems, you can set a flag to enable the occurs check for *all* unifications.

For example, in SWI-Prolog:

```
?- set_prolog_flag(occurs_check, true).
true.

?- X = f(X).
false.
```

I recommend you enable this flag to get sound results.

Unifications that *require* the occurs check often indicate programming errors. For this reason, you can set the flag to throw *errors* instead of failing silently.

See also the [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33751209/prolog-matching-vs-minikanren-unification/33753953#33753953) linked to by @false in the comments above, and the cited reference.

Comment: Please do not forget to mention `set_prolog_flag(occurs_check, error)` which is probably the best for beginners.

Comment: What is an example of unsound inference when unification allows cyclic terms?