# Prolog : coin change

Tags: prolog, coin-change

I am new to prolog, trying to solve this classic coin change problem.

change(M,P,N,D) with formula that M>=0  and M = P+5*N+10*D
here is my approach

```
change(M,P,N,D) :-
     M is P+5*N+10*D,
     P is M - (5*N+10*10).
```

couple of test-cases

```
  change(100,10,8,5).
  True
  change(X,10,8,5).
  X = 100.
```

However, if I try

```
 change(100,P,8,5).
```

it gives me "Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated" instead of P = 10.
what is casuing this ?

edit : fix my code by using between predicate
between(0,M,P),between(0,M,N),between(0,M,D),M is P+5*N+10*D.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prolog Break Money into Smaller Amounts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29338495/prolog-break-money-into-smaller-amounts)

Comment: The reason why you get the error is that `is/2` evaluates an _arithmetic expression_: it is **not** a purely "logical" predicate. You already seem to know at least one way to solve this; see the duplicate question and the answer for a better way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Use [clpfd](/questions/tagged/clpfd)!**

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).
```

All we need to express `change/4` is *one* equation:

```
change(Money,Pennies,Nickels,Dimes) :-
   Money #= Pennies + Nickels*5 + Dimes*10.
```

Let's run the ground query given by the OP!

```
?- change(100,10,8,5).
true.
```

Next up, four queries having exactly *one* variable:

```
?- change(Money,10,8,5).
Money = 100.

?- change(100,Pennies,8,5).
Pennies = 10.

?- change(100,10,Nickels,5).
Nickels = 8.

?- change(100,10,8,Dimes).
Dimes = 5.
```

---

As we are using [clpfd](/questions/tagged/clpfd), we can also ask more general queries, like this one with *three* variables:

```
?- change(100,Pennies,Nickels,Dimes).
100 #= Pennies + 5*Nickels + 10*Dimes.
```

Note that this does not (yet) enumerate all possible combinations... to do so takes two steps:

1. State that "all counts are non-negative" by using [`ins/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/man/clpfd.html):

   ```
   ?- [Pennies,Nickels,Dimes] ins 0..sup,
      change(100,Pennies,Nickels,Dimes).
   100 #= Pennies + 5*Nickels + 10*Dimes,
   Pennies in 0..100,
   Nickels in 0..20,
   Dimes   in 0..10.
   ```
2. Use the enumeration predicate [`labeling/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/man/clpfd.html):

   ```
   ?- Zs = [Pennies,Nickels,Dimes],
      Zs ins 0..sup,
      change(100,Pennies,Nickels,Dimes),
      labeling([],Zs).
     Pennies = 0  , Nickels = 0, Dimes = 10
   ; Pennies = 0  , Nickels = 2, Dimes = 9
   ; Pennies = 0  , Nickels = 4, Dimes = 8
   % the next 115 answers were omitted for the sake of brevity
   ; Pennies = 90 , Nickels = 2, Dimes = 0
   ; Pennies = 95 , Nickels = 1, Dimes = 0
   ; Pennies = 100, Nickels = 0, Dimes = 0
   ; false.
   ```