# How to reify Prolog's backtracking state to perform the same task as "lazy seq" from Clojure?

Tags: clojure, prolog, quicksort, lazy-sequences, reify

Here is a quicksort algorithm for numbers written in Clojure. It is basically the quicksort algorithm found in *"The Joy of Clojure"*, 2nd edition, page 133. I modified it slightly for (hopefully) better readability, because the original felt a bit too compact:

```
(defn qsort-inner [work]
   (lazy-seq        
      (loop [loopwork work]
         (let [[ part & partz ] loopwork ]
            (if-let [[pivot & valuez] (seq part)]
                  (let [ smaller? #(< % pivot)
                         smz      (filter smaller? valuez)
                         lgz      (remove smaller? valuez)
                         nxxt     (list* smz pivot lgz partz) ]
                        (recur nxxt))
                  (if-let [[oldpivot & rightpartz] partz]
                          (cons oldpivot (qsort-inner rightpartz))
                          []))))))

(defn qsort [ xs ]
   (qsort-inner (list xs)))
```

The algorithm is started by a call to `qsort`, which envelops a passed list of numbers into another list (thus creating a list containing a single list), then calls `qsort-inner`.

```
(qsort [10 4 5 88 7 1])     ;; (qsort-inner [[10 4 5 88 7 1]])
;; (1 4 5 7 10 88)
```

`qsort-inner` has three noteworthy points:

- It delays actual processing. Instead of returning the result of a complete sorting of the input list, it returns a "lazy-seq", which is an (object? thing? [thunk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thunk)?) that emits the next number of the sorted sequence when queried, i.e. sorts on an as-needed basis. The state of the computation is given by the suspended tail of `(cons oldpivot (qsort-inner rightpartz))`
- There is a `loop` + `recur` tail-recursive part which is used whenever the algorithm wanders down the sorting tree "towards the left" (see below for algorithm details.)
- There is a fully recursive call `(qsort-inner rightpartz)` which is used when the next least number has been obtained and the sorting tree can be "re-arranged" (see below for algorithm details.)

With the help of the `lazy-seq` thing, we can make the algorithm emit data one-by-one:

```
;; the full result is generated on printout
(qsort [10 4 5 88 7 1])
(1 4 5 7 10 88)

;; store the lazy-seq and query it
(def l (qsort [10 4 5 88 7 1]))
(first l)
;; 1
(second l)
;; 4
```

I was thinking about how to perform this lazy quicksort in Prolog. In fact, laziness, at least in this instance, is given for free in Prolog by backtracking! We can ask for a first result, computation halts and the next result is then obtained by backtracking.

```
qsort_inner(X, [[],X|_]).
qsort_inner(X, [[],_|WorkRest]) :- qsort_inner(X, WorkRest).
qsort_inner(X, [[Piv|Ns]|WorkRest]) :- 
    pick_smaller(Piv,Ns,SMs),
    pick_notsmaller(Piv,Ns,NSMs),
    qsort_inner(X,[SMs,Piv,NSMs|WorkRest]).

pick_smaller(Pivot,Ins,Outs) :- include(@>(Pivot),Ins,Outs).
pick_notsmaller(Pivot,Ins,Outs) :- exclude(@>(Pivot),Ins,Outs).

qsort(X,Lin) :- qsort_inner(X,[Lin]).
```

Sort a list "lazily":

```
qsort(X,[3,2,1]).
X = 1;
X = 2;
X = 3;
false
```

Gotta get them all:

```
qsort_fully(Lin,Lout) :- bagof(X, qsort(X, Lin), Lout).
```

Unfortunately, the data structure that keeps track of the computational state is not apparent: it is on the stack, it cannot be unified to a variable. Thus is can only use this kind of "laziness" when I am on Prolog's top level.

How do I capture the state of the computation and invoke it later?

**Note on how the quick sort works**

- Given a list of numbers, the algorithm selects the first element of the list as pivot value (light green in the image).
- It then builds a tree with those numbers strictly smaller than the pivot value in a list "on the left", the pivot itself (dark green) and those numbers larger or equal to the pivot value as a list "on the right".
- It then recursively moves down this tree "towards the left".
- This continues until the list of numbers smaller than the pivot value is empty.
- At that point, the pivot value (here, 28) is the least number overall and can be output.
- This makes the list to sort one element smaller. The tree can now be reduced by one level with a trivial rearrangement operation: the right branch of the now left-branch-less and pivot-less "deepest tree-node but one" becomes the left branch of the tree node "deepest tree-node but two".
- Searching for the least element can now proceed again "towards the left".

The tree structure does not need to be explicitly kept as it holds no information. Instead, the sequence of alternating "leaf lists" and "pivot numbers" is kept in a list. Which is why we the intial "list of a lits of numbers".

[image: Partial example run for quicksort]

Comment: I read this and think you have not really asked the question to the problem you need help solving. You have taken guesses at what might solve the problem and given examples, but the example is the best way to understand the idea in your head at present. As many times as I think reify is the answer, it turns out latter to not really be needed. Sometimes the answer is to use BFS instead of the default DFS. Sometimes it is to use difference list which are more easily done as DCGS.

Comment: Perhaps one of these have the answer you seek: [Difference Lists](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~fp/courses/lp/lectures/11-diff.pdf) by Frank Pfenning or [sorting algorithms implemented in Prolog](https://www.metalevel.at/misc/sorting.pl) by Markus Triska

Comment: Of interest: [lazy_lists.pl](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/_SWI_/library/lazy_lists.pl)

Comment: I recommend [Lazy lists in Prolog?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8869485/849891), with two approaches -- a [more involved one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8882745/849891) with stateful generators (disclaimer, that answer is by me) and the more [direct and simple one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14514298/849891), with `freeze/2` (also, https://gist.github.com/mndrix/4644762). Or some combination of the two. :)

Comment: @DanielLyons [`next/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8882745/849891) -- the current state is also needed. :) (not so messy, I think.)

Comment: @WillNess Nice!

Comment: @DanielLyons thanks. :) I didn't know about `freeze/2` at the time. had to get by without it. :)

Comment: Good comments. Good answers. I will have to choose ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Prolog is a very reifiable language. Just turn your code into data:

```erlang
qsort_gen(Lin, G) :- 
    % G is the initial generator state for Lin's quicksorting
    G = qsort_inner([Lin]).

    %    This_State                   Next_Elt      Next_State
next( qsort_inner([[], X    | WorkRest]), X, qsort_inner(WorkRest) ).
next( qsort_inner([[Piv|Ns] | WorkRest]), X, G ) :-
    pick_smaller(  Piv, Ns, SMs),
    pick_notsmaller(Piv, Ns, NSMs),
    next( qsort_inner([SMs, Piv, NSMs | WorkRest]), X, G).

pick_smaller(  Pivot, Ins, Outs) :- include( @>(Pivot), Ins, Outs).
pick_notsmaller(Pivot, Ins, Outs) :- exclude( @>(Pivot), Ins, Outs).
```

That's all.

```erlang
15 ?- qsort_gen([3,2,5,1,9,4,8], G), next(G,X,G2), next(G2,X2,G3), next(G3,X3,G4).
G = qsort_inner([[3, 2, 5, 1, 9, 4, 8]]),
X = 1,
G2 = qsort_inner([[], 2, [], 3, [5, 9, 4|...]]),
X2 = 2,
G3 = qsort_inner([[], 3, [5, 9, 4, 8]]),
X3 = 3,
G4 = qsort_inner([[5, 9, 4, 8]]).

16 ?- qsort_gen([1,9,4,8], G), next(G,X,G2), next(G2,X2,G3), next(G3,X3,G4).
G = qsort_inner([[1, 9, 4, 8]]),
X = 1,
G2 = qsort_inner([[9, 4, 8]]),
X2 = 4,
G3 = qsort_inner([[8], 9, []]),
X3 = 8,
G4 = qsort_inner([[], 9, []]).

17 ?- qsort_gen([1,9,4], G), next(G,X,G2), next(G2,X2,G3), next(G3,X3,G4).
G = qsort_inner([[1, 9, 4]]),
X = 1,
G2 = qsort_inner([[9, 4]]),
X2 = 4,
G3 = qsort_inner([[], 9, []]),
X3 = 9,
G4 = qsort_inner([[]]).
```

For easier interfacing, we can use [`take/4`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8882745/849891):

```erlang
take( 0, Next, Z-Z, Next):- !.
take( N, Next, [A|B]-Z, NextZ):- N>0, !, next( Next, A, Next1),
  N1 is N-1,
  take( N1, Next1, B-Z, NextZ).
```

Then,

```erlang
19 ?- qsort_gen([3,2,5,1,9,4,8], G), take(6, G, L-[], _).
G = qsort_inner([[3, 2, 5, 1, 9, 4, 8]]),
L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8].

20 ?- qsort_gen([3,2,5,1,9,4,8], G), take(7, G, L-[], _).
G = qsort_inner([[3, 2, 5, 1, 9, 4, 8]]),
L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9].

21 ?- qsort_gen([3,2,5,1,9,4,8], G), take(10, G, L-[], _).
false.
```

`take/4` obviously needs tweaking to close the output list gracefully when `next/3` fails. It was written with the infinite lists in mind, originally. This is left as an exercise for a keen explorer.

Comment: Nice! I was checking out Markus Triska's [prost.pl](https://www.metalevel.at/various/prost.pl) late at night but I didn't click.

Comment: I have been in pointy {} languages for so long that my sense of seeing code as data has atrophied. It's a conspiracy.

Comment: Prolog is special. It's much more Lispier than Lisp in this regard, I think. ( I like to say sometimes that compiling was a trillion dollars mistake. But really it's not compiling per se, but the distribution of binaries without the sources which is that. IMO. )

Answer (score 4):

This isn't standardized, but a number of Prologs nowadays provide facilities to maintain and manipulate multiple independent backtrackable states, often known as **engines**.

For example, using the corresponding [primitives](https://eclipseclp.org/doc/bips/kernel/engines/index.html) in [ECLiPSe](https://eclipseclp.org), you might write

```
init(Vars, Goal, Engine) :-
    engine_create(Engine, []),
    engine_resume(Engine, (true;Goal,yield(Vars,Cont),Cont), true).

more(Engine, Vars) :-
    engine_resume(Engine, fail, yielded(Vars)).
```

and use that as follows (with `qsort/2` as defined by you)

```
?- init(X, qsort(X,[3,2,1]), Eng),
   more(Eng, X1),
   more(Eng, X2),
   more(Eng, X3).

X = X
Eng = $&(engine,"9wwqv3")
X1 = 1
X2 = 2
X3 = 3
Yes (0.00s cpu)
```

Here, the variable `Eng` is bound to an opaque *engine*-handle.  This *engine* executes a nondeterministic goal that yields a new solution to the caller every time it is resumed and instructed to backtrack.

Comment: SWI-Prolog appears to have [something similar](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=engine-examples) using `engine_create/3` and `engine_next/2` ([API docs](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=engine-predicates)).